# Jquery / Bootstrap not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello i have an issue i have been trying to solve for days concerning the javascript on my website.  I use both jqueryui and bootstrap but for some reason i am unable to call any functions present in both libraries.  It worked initially when i began development of the website but suddenly stopped working.  I use firebug and have not detected any javascript or network errors on my page when it loads except when i try to cal a function from one of the libraries. eg.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#DoB").datepicker({
            inline: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code used to work now when the page loads i get "datepicker is not a function".
I do not know what is causing this issue.  I assumed at first that it might be due to some conflicting javascript files in my website but i took out all .js files except the two libraries  (jquery, jqueryui) but it still did not work.

This is how my header looks:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
    <title>***</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascipt" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
```

This is how my footer looks:

```
<script type="text/javascipt" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/unslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>
<?php
    foreach ($enqueue as $js) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/" . $js . "'></script>";
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSearch").click(function() {
            var p = $(".search-field").val();
            window.location.href = "index.php?page=search&p=" + p;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is a screenshot of my firebug console:
[image]

I have this issue not just with the datepicker function alone. I experience the same problems with my bootstrap.min.js and i cannot understand why so i would really like to have some help with this.  I experience this issue in firefox, chrome and opera on both my localhost and the online server as well.

Comment: Can you run the code to initialize the datepicker inside console windows of your browser? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes i get the same error i stated before in my post "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function" or "TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function"

Comment: In your footer, inside the PHP foreach, what is the contents of the $enqueue array? Just checking you are not calling jquery again?

Comment: No i am calling a page unique javascript file.  The functions in such files are only unique to particular pages only tht is why i do not just include it all in the header or footer.

Comment: OK last suggestion, try view page source and search (Ctrl + f) for "jquery", double check it has not been called again after your jqueryui. Good luck

Comment: I have no idea what is happening, i checked like you asked and there was only one jquery file include within my application.

Comment: Since i am not getting any solution for this i would like a professional opinion, do you think i should strip the project and recreate it from scratch or should i wait a while to see if any one can come up with a solution.  I have a deadline for this.